# How to get the "body" and "subject" fields of a draft when extending compose UI?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, add-on

We are developing a Gmail Addon in which we [extend the compose UI](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui).

This extends the compose window in which you can compose your e-mail.

We need the 'From', 'To', 'Subject' and 'Body' of the message that is being composed.

The 'From' can be read from the Session object like this

`var mySelf = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();`

The 'To' can be read from the draftMetadata from the event object of the function being called.

```
function composeEmail(event) { console.log(event.draftMetadata.toRecipients); }
```

The 'Subject' and 'Body' can't be read from the event object of the function since it is a composeTrigger. The argument contains these objects:

```
{
  formInput = {}, 
  clientPlatform = web, 
  formInputs = {}, 
  parameters = {}, 
  draftMetadata = {
    toRecipients = [test @test.com],
    subject = ,
    bccRecipients = [],
    ccRecipients = []
  }
}
```

Surprisingly to me, the subject key is there but not being filled in (yes I did type in a subject).

**Question**:

How can I get the 'Subject' and 'Body' of the E-mail being composed by the user in the extended composer UI?

**Extra information**:

The contextual trigger action contains the following object as event object:

```
{
  clientPlatform = web, 
  messageMetadata = {
    messageId = 16e agg7323451256989f68,
    accessToken = AAGdOAawdaAOW8PWchmdawdk0N13STKnBPMAOXVjZVHyQMfAawdBtgEIrS6N8y5h2BOZnKFPlfsl5VBsyPiF7YiONOoP7XVjKZawdi - E6vI - jVU92dPmfj3RNmXfawdawdeaNMrXehAFLm
  }
}
```

By reading an email through the contextual trigger a `messageId` is being added in which the `getBody` and `getSubject` methods can be used.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, the Compose Trigger Event never returns the value of the `subject` field.

I have filled a bug for this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145262033). Click the ★ icon to follow this Issue and get updates. This will also help prioritize this Issue.

As a workaround, you can use the contextual trigger to:

1. Get the `messageId`
2. Find drafts that have that `messageId` associated to them
3. Get the draft by their `draftId`
4. Fetch the subject line from the `Headers` object on the draft.

This only works on drafts that are replying to a specific message.

Comment: Hi Raserhin, thank you for filling in the issue. I have starred the issue to help prioritize the issue. 

The contextual trigger is an option indeed for only replying. We do really need it when composing a message aswell, which seems no option to do so for now.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now so I can see read `gmail.subject` property. It is so utterly bizarre and disappointing though that I cannot access the message for which the reply was created inside compose. The `contextualTriggers` lets me do all kinds of clever things since I can tell what the source message is. Even with the full `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly` scope I can't see the 'replyTo' message under compose. Don't really understand the point of the compose UI if it can't be dynamic :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before so this is a guess.  I looked at the compose dialog html with the developer tools and this is what I noticed.

[image]

There seem to be a bunch of hidden inputs that are used to store values that are typed into  the compose dialog.  So I would try something like:
formInputs.body or perhaps formInput.body taking the name of the key from names of this hidden elements.  This is just a guess.

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you for your guess. The code of the App Script is being executed in the back-end so any client-side variables like `window` or `document` aren't available. This way there is no possibility to read anything from the rendered front-end